# Spring boot functional endpoints not handling the error when request body is not available

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I create a POST method by spring boot functional endpoint. And I added @NotNull @NotEmpty annotation on request class. And using springframework Validator for validation. My request body is

```
class Person {
    @NotNull  @NotEmpty   private String name;
    @NotNull  @NotEmpty   private String age;
}
```

The validation working when name or age is/are empty, but it's not working/handling, if I didn't pass any body on post method ( I use postman for testing) I created a handler method on flatmap, but the flatmap not executing if requestbody not present. So the ServerResponse always returning OK status 200.

```
serverRequest.bodyToMono(Person.class)
            .flatMap(person -> requestValidationHandler.createGroupRequestValidation(person))
```

Comment: you should use `switchIfEmpty` https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#switchIfEmpty-reactor.core.publisher.Mono-

Comment: Thank you @ThomasAndolf but I want to throw an exception when the request body is not present/ coming while call the endpoint. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, it's working switchIfEmpty(Mono.Error (myException)); but can you clarify?How we can determine whether it occurred due to bad request or some other problem?

Comment: It's only useful for which endpoint return something. But I have some scenarios such a POST call with request body and it won't return any value. We are considering if status 200, its success call. So it's giving 200 even if I am not passing request body. How to handle this scenario ?

Comment: there are 3 ways of handling data. Null is not allowed in reactive flows. You should return from functions Mono<T> if there is a value, Mono<Void> (mono empty) if you dont want to return anything but you can recover or want to continue execution. And then Mono error, when you want to abort the reactive chain and return an error. Then you can do things as switch if an empty comes, you can do something if you are returning an error. All this is in the reactor documentation.

Comment: you are asking me, "how should we do when this, and that... and etc" read the reactor documentation. Learn how to do things and what tools you have. Then you will be able to build your flows, because you know what tools you have at hand.